# Regular expression to extract texts between square brackets

Tags: regex

I want to extract the texts from between the square brackets and i am using `[(.*?)]` but it is not working completely.

> Apr 17 13:01:34 10.11.26.83 2012-04-17 00:30:52.222 -0700  ABCD XYZ ALER SOME_TEXT 99.99.182.1 49923 99.99.83.74 80 blocked-policy GLOBAL DENY NONE [**type="SOME TEXT" pattern="some-random-pattern" token="/function()"**] GET 99.99.83.74/index.html/function() HTTP "-" "Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)" 99.99.182.1 49923 "-" "-"

I want to extract the **bold** texts. What is the regular expression to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by not working completely? I used your regex and you already have the required match in group 1.

Comment: It looks as if your error is somewhere else because the regex you are using is correct.

Comment: and how about all-eating `.`? as i remember, it doesn't eat `\n`. maybe i'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rprakash:

**Anatomy of the pattern**

```
<!--
\[(.*?)\]

Match the character “[” literally «\[»  
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»  
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»  
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»  
Match the character “]” literally «\]»  
-->
```

While using **REGEX** it is always safe to use **negated character class** instead of **dot** operator.

It might be `\[[^\]]+\]` as Bohemian said, or may be safer to use `\[(?#if grouping required)([^\]\[]+)\]`.

For making better footholds in this subject [visit here](http://www.regexbuddy.com/library.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\[[^\]]+\]
```

`[^\]]` is a character class for "any character other than a ]"